# Shortcode is not working correctly if it is used more then one time in a same page

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, html

I have created one shortcode to return a tab content and it is working fine 
if I am using one time in a page.But if want one more on this same page it is not working. I have tried in several way but its not giving fruits.

Here is the code

```
if($tab_box == 'tab_box_1' && $tabs_lay == 'awavc-tabs-pos-left') {
           $add_class = rand(99,9999);
           $q = rand(99,99999);
$html .= '
<div class="awavc-tabs awavc-tabs-'.$add_class.' '.$tabs_lay.' '.$tab_style.' awavc-tabs-response-to-icons '.$el_class.' ">';
$i = 1;
        foreach($tab_contents as $tab_content){

             $tab_lable = 'Lable';
             $tab_icon = '';



            if(!empty($tab_content['tab_lbl'])){$tab_lable = $tab_content['tab_lbl'];}
            if(!empty($tab_content['icon'])){$tab_icon = $tab_content['icon'];}
                $html .= '  <input type="radio" name="awavc-tabs" checked id="awavc-tab-'.$i.'" class="awavc-tab-content-'.$i.'">
                            <label for="awavc-tab-'.$i.'"><span><span style="font-size:'.$lable_size.'px;color:'.$lable_clr.';"><i class="'.$tab_icon.'" style="font-size:'.$lable_size.'px;color:'.$icon_clr.';"></i>'.$tab_lable.'</span></span></label>';
                            $i++;

        }

$html .= '
            <ul>';
            $i = 1;
            foreach($tab_contents as $tab_content){

                $tab_title = 'Title';
                $content = '';

                if(!empty($tab_content['title'])){$tab_title = $tab_content['title'];}
                if(!empty($tab_content['content'])){$content = $tab_content['content'];}

                $html .= '<li class="awavc-tab-content-'.$i.'">
                    <div class="typography">';
                        if(!empty($tab_title)){ $html .= '<h1 style="font-size:'.$ttl_size.'px;color:'.$ttl_clr.';">'.$tab_title.'</h1>';}

                        $html .= '
                        <p style="font-size:'.$content_size.'px;color:'.$content_clr.';font-style:'.$content_style.';">'.$content.'</p>


                    </div>
                </li>';
                $i++;
                }
```

**I have tried something like $i.$add_class but...**

Comment: Can you provide the full declaration of your custom shortcode? By that, I mean the everything including the add_shortcode declaration that exists in your functions.php file.

Comment: This question should be moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the shortcode multiple times on the same page do it like so:

```
add_shortcode("fmg_shortcode", "fmg_callback");

function fmg_callback($args) {

ob_start();

$html = "";

//your code here

echo $html;

return ob_get_clean();

}
```

Comment: If you can provide full declaration like Ryan said it would make it more clear